# What is the moduli space of $n\times n$ matrices with values on some field $k$ under conjugation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

Maybe we can start with an easy example. I want to understand what is the moduli space of say $1\times 1$ matrices under conjugation. So if such a matrix is $A$, the conjugation means $A = G^{-1}AG$ where say $G\in GL_n$. What is the moduli space then? And what is the corresponding moduli space for $2\times 2$ such matrices? Let's say that $k = \mathbb{C}$. What is the moduli space for $n \times n$ such matrices? And do singularities appear?

This is the first question a speaker asked at a seminar last week. And I really want to understand not only what the moduli space of such matrices is but also when and why singularities appear.

Comment: Do you mean, What is the structure of the space $M_n(k) / \sim$, where $A \sim B$ if $A$ and $B$ are similar?

Comment: Was that a rethorical question? If so, you could try asking the speaker him/herself...

Comment: No, I'm asking OP to verify that this is precisely what they mean by moduli space here. (Or is interpreting what the speaker meant by this term part of OP's question?)

Comment: You made me smile @Travis. My question was directed at the OP, regarding the intent behind the speaker's question. :)

Comment: Mumford has a beautiful expository paper about this. http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/1972d--IntroModuli-NC.pdf

Comment: Hi, indeed, what is the moduli space of such matrices modulo conjugation by elements of the general linear group. Understanding this will help me understand better the moduli space of instantons, or if you wish unframed torsion free sheaves satisfying the ASD equations. I know that my question is somehow related to the Jordan form. But nothing is clear to me right now.

Comment: For example for 2x2 matrices with complex values, if we consider them as modules over a ring, and if we take their Jordan form such that they do not have any non-trivial submodules I think that the moduli space is $\mathbb{C^2}/S_2 = Sym^{2}(\mathbb{C}^2)$